# Simulating the paste's event automated scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with a `<div contenteditable></div>` element, and I wanted to override the default paste event to remove all sorts of formatting.

```
document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").addEventListener("paste", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain"));
});
```

It works, but when pasting something, once it overflows the current scrolled area, it is required for the user to scroll down manually.

[image]

I've thought about scrolling into the caret's location, but I have no idea how to do this, as it is not a DOM element. What could be the solution to the problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361276/javascript-scroll-to-cursor-post-a-paste-in-contenteditable-div
This might be the answer.